# Building Function Model , not sure about my answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A proposed energy tax 
T
 on gasoline, which would affect the cost of driving a vehicle, is to be computed by multiplying the number 
x
 of gallons of gasoline by 125,000 (the number of BTUs per gallon) and then multiplying the total BTUs by the tax ($0.342 per 1,000,000 BTUs). Find a linear function for 
T
 in terms of 
x
.

for this question the answer I got was:

T(x) = x*125000 * 0.342/1000000

Edit: The instructor gave no answer, its a practice problem , I don't know if its right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is wrong. Here's why:

The **tax** is charged by $\frac{0.342}{1,000,000}\frac{$}{BTUs}$. Since each gallons have $125000$ **BTUs**, it's $\frac{1}{4}$ of the tax charged over $1,000,000$ **BTUs** (I'm doing $\frac{125,000}{1,000,000}$). In other words, we have to compute the function $T: x \rightarrow $$ as such:

$T(x) = 125,000x*\frac{0,342}{8} \Leftrightarrow T(x) = 15,625x*0,342 \Leftrightarrow T(x) = 5,343.75x$, where $x$ is the number of **gallons**.

Comment: I don't understand how you got 0.342/4 , can you clarify?

Comment: Yes. I did $\frac{0.342$}{1,000,000BTUs} * 125,000 BTUs$.

Comment: Basically, the charge is $\frac{$}{BTUs}$. I multiplied the charge by the number of **BTUs** in a gallon

Comment: would it not be /8 ?

Comment: If a gallon would have $8$ times the number of BTUs charged with the thax $0,342$, we would endup with $0,342*8$, for example

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. It is $\frac{1}{8}$ lol

Comment: omg I was so confused lol,

Comment: Lol, I can imagine. So sorry and thanks for catching the error

Comment: would the tax rate change as well, as if we convert 0.342 per million, then that would be 2.736 per 125k , does that make sense?

Comment: Almost, unstead od multiplying $0,342$ by $8$, we divide it, becausing we are cutting $\frac{1}{8}$ of the **BTUs**

Comment: so the correct answer is : T(x) = 125000x * (0.04275)/8

Comment: $ T(x) = 125000x * (0.04275)$, without the $\frac{1}{8}$ that you already divided from the $0,342$

Comment: ok, everything is now making sense, thanks for your time sir

Comment: thanks for you question